# How to organize array with different types?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi,

I am new in Java and trying to figure out how to push this data into array(6 rows, 3 columns)?

```
x1 John 6
x2 Smith 9
x3 Alex 7
y1 Peter 8
y2 Frank 9
y3 Andy 4
```

Afterwards, I will take numbers from last column for making mathematical calculations.

This is my code...

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee eh = new Employee_hour();

        Employee_hour [] eh_list = new Employee_hour[6];
        eh_list[0] = new Employee_hour("x1", "John", 6);
        eh_list[1] = new Employee_hour("x2", "Smith", 9);
        eh_list[2] = new Employee_hour("x3", "Alex", 7);
        eh_list[3] = new Employee_hour("y1", "Peter", 8);
        eh_list[4] = new Employee_hour("y2", "Frank", 9);
        eh_list[5] = new Employee_hour("y3", "Andy", 4);
        print(eh_list);
    }

    private static void print(Employee_hour[] mass){
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(mass[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this as the output...

> testing.Employee_hour@1a752144 testing.Employee_hour@7fdb04ed
>   testing.Employee_hour@420a52f testing.Employee_hour@7b3cb2c6
>   testing.Employee_hour@4dfd245f testing.Employee_hour@265f00f9

How can I get numbers from last column?

Comment: does it need to be an array? its not the most efficient datastructure

Comment: Do you have to use arrays or is it ok to use other data structures ? What is the data representing and how are going to use it ? If you put the data in an Object[][] array it will be cumbersome to use that data afterward.

Comment: If it doesnt have to be an array, it might be worth looking into using a map.

Comment: Also note, your first `Employee eh = new Employee_hour();` does nothing and is redundant.

Answer (score 9):

Why not create a specific Java bean for your records?

```
class Person {
  String id;
  String name;
  int anotherNumber;
  // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Person [] people = new Person[10];
people[0] = new Person("x1", "John", 6);
...
```

Or better yet employ `java.util.List` instead of the array.

**Field Access**

In order to access separate fields, you either need to make your fields public (very bad idea) and simply refer to them as `object_instance.field_name`, or provide so-called getters:

```
class Person {
  String id;
  String name;
  int anotherNumber;
  // constructor, getters, setters

  public int getAnotherNumber() {
     return anotherNumber;
  }
}
```

Then call it when printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(mass[i].getAnotherNumber() + " ");
}
```

**Why what you tried didn't work:**

`System.out.println(mass[0])` in your case will print the whole object representation, by default it prints what it did in your case. To do it nicer you need to override `Object`'s `String toString()` method:

```
class Person {
  String id;
  String name;
  int anotherNumber;
  // constructor, getters, setters

  public String toString() {
     return "{id="+id+", name="+name+", anotherNumber="+anotherNumber+"}";
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this approach, especially the `List` suggestion. I would use `ArrayList` with generics, so that you would only be able to pass `Person` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Java is strongly typed, so you can't just make an array that will accept any type.
However, you could make a multidimensional array of type `Object`, and use `java.lang.Integer` for the integer values.
The alternative is to make a class that represents the rows in your table, and make an array of that class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store it as array user 2 dimentional array.Here is a sample.

```
String[][] a2 = new String[10][5];
   for (int i=0; i<a2.length; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<a2[i].length; j++) {
   a2[i][j] = i;
   System.out.print(" " + a2[i][j]);
   }
   System.out.println("");
   }
  }
```

The better approach would be to cretae an Object

```
class User {
  String id;
  String userName;
  int userSomeValue;

 //
}
```

Then push it to a list

```
User ob1=new User();
// set the values.
List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
userList.add(ob1);
```

Use this list for procesing by retriving the contents using

```
userList.get(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is a type-safe collection you can use array of generic objects. Other way use `collection Api`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to store your data in an array but you can only store values of the same type in one Array. For Example just String, int or float. In your case you have to use String but you can't do any calculations with a string type variable even if it contains a number. I would suggest the way maksimov describes.